# Is it safe to "require()" an external authentication file rather than have it in the code directly in "sensitive" pages that need to be secured?

Tags: php, authentication

**The short of it:**

Is it generally concidred safe to "require()" an authentication.php file rather than actually have the code on each page for easy update?

**The long of it:**

(Clarity Edit: I realize that fully securing my site is out of my scope of possibility. I'm mostly just wondering if its a 100% no no to require the authentication code and its a MUST to actually paste the hard code on each page. Or if generally inserting a single authentication code file at the top of pages needed is alright)

I'm sorry, I'm sure this is a stupid question but I want to double check. I'm working on authenticating portation of my site, and I have simple code like this so far to accomplish it (obviously some external functions not shown or needed)

```
<?php
if(!request_is_same_domain()){
    redirect_to(url_for('/index.php'));
}else{

if (!$session->is_logged_in()) {
    redirect_to(url_for('/mission_control/login.php'));
}elseif($session->account_type() != "admin"){
    $session->message =  "Sorry you seemed to stray into an unknown area of the website";
    redirect_to(url_for('/mission_control/login.php'));
}
}
```

?>

Is it okay to take this simple code chunk and break it off into a separate file that is hidden in a private directory, then "require()" it at the top of all pages that need authenticating? If the code isn't directly on the pages that need protecting does this leave me open to some type of workaround for "hackers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technology is constantly evolving the matter about securing an application is really a broad topic to start with. Sometimes no matter how we like to keep our codes secure we vulnerabilities will keep on coming to keep your website secured and safe from any vulnerabilities keep the server and its modules updated but this will really be a lot of work than you think that is if you really put security in mind you will truly give time keeping the server up for the latest updates and maintain a stronger authentication method on who gets to access your server example by using ssh keys, but as I said security is really a broad topic technology keeps on evolving what we consider secure now might not be secured in the future.

Comment: I appreciate the response  very much. I probably should have been more clear though. I understand that keeping a REALLY secure website is a full time job by experts that is out of my scope. I'm basicly wondering if its required that I have the actual authentication code i'm working on on every page, or if its basically almost the same thing if i require a single file with that code at the top of pages its needed. Or more  generally, are there any REALLY glaring reasons I SHOULD DEFINITELY NOT require a separate file and instead copy and paste the code manually on each page?

Comment: for me it would be fine but when you said security and mention about hackers which is why I thought you mean about a full server security including code file access. for easier app maintenance and update that would be fine I think as long as your the only one who knows where the files are located to and permissions are properly set.

Comment: fantastic. Thank you very much! sorry for the confusion :).